# Showing views like Safari

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I am having a grid of views that is currently shown in a simple grid architecture. But I want to know how can I show it in curved architecture as follows:

[image]

Comment: I've been looking through [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) (look for the "Graphics & Animation" samples, especially); I'm pretty certain there should be some Core Image or Core Filter that does roughly what you are looking for.  They've demoed stuff like this at WWDC repeatedly.

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is mask a layer with a CGPath.  The websites themselves don't appear to be distorted, just the edges of the view.

Comment: @CodaFi: Can you provide some code snippet doing this trick? I just need to put my views in curved shape as shown.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I went through most of samples under "Graphics & Animation category, but could not find something apposite to my need. Can you point me to the specific video/presentation at WWDC which covers this trick???